# How to determine where the matrix elements go for the general angular momentum matrix in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, matrix-elements

Hello I have question on how to determine the matrix elements for the general angular momentum operator. So I know that $\langle j',m' \vert J^2 \vert j,m \rangle = (\hbar)j(j+1)\delta_{(j′j)}δ_{(m′m)}$. Now this has been used in the following example question 5.3a.

**My question is how do you go about choosing which matrix elements corresponds to which

$\langle j',m'|J^2|j,m \rangle$ coefficient. For example with what rule has the author chosen to make the first matrix element (in the 1,1 position) be $\langle 1,1 \vert J^2 \vert 1,1 \rangle $? Similarly why is $\langle 1,0 \vert J^2 \vert1,0 \rangle$ in the 2,2 matrix position?**

I have tried to reason it with myself and the only pattern I can find is that the author has decided to denote the matrix rows and columns by the m and since j=1 so m=1,0,-1. It seems that the author goes in that order for m so the 1,1 position is denoted by m=1,1 and the 1,2 matrix position is denoted by 1,0 and so on. If this is true then is it always true that we denote matrix elements by the m values and go in a descending order? So for j=2 then m=2,1,0,-1,-2 and this will correspond to a 5x5 matrix.

This pattern seems to work for the J- and J+ operators below. However I am skeptical and would like guidance. I have attached a picture from my textbook for the example question 5.3a that I referred to.

[image]

Comment: Please use mathJax formatting instead of pictures and actually format your equations.

Comment: < a | a > can be written in latex as \langle a \vert a \rangle inside of $$

Comment: A specification of a basis consists of both a spanning set of linearly independent vectors *and an order* for this set of vectors.  This is true in linear algebra in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These matrices are a way of bookkeeping your coefficients. There isn't a "right" answer, but you need to keep your notation consistent when problem solving (i.e. use the proper physical entities corresponding to the appropriate j and m values when needed). Usually a logical answer is chosen as you have noted in your post (e.g. going in some sort of consistent order).